# Selenium will not load in Pycharm

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I want to use Selenium, but when I write `from selenium import webbrowser` it returns the following error:

> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.3\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
>       module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

I have ran `pip install selenium` and unstalled it several times. I also tried to set my project interpreter in Pycharm to where the selenium files are saved. (Selenium is saved here: C:\Users[my name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages).

I have also tried to set my environment variables to `"C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python;C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib;C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs;C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Progr"`

At this point, I'm confused what is causing the problem. I am new to Python and have read several posts online, but nothing seem to fix my problem.

Comment: Did you try creating a virtual environment and installing it there?

Comment: I have tried creating a viritual environment, but not sure if I did install Selenium in there. Two questions: (1) where should I set my location and base interpreter for the new viritual environment? (2) How do i get Selenium in that environment?

Comment: It worked! Creating a new virtual environment in an empty file, setting the base interpreter to ...\Scripts\python.exe. 

Why did it work? Selenium is still installed in \Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages whereas my base interpreter is running from \Scripts\python.exe.

Comment: I'm not sure about the details, but glad it worked!